# Difference between universal and nth-child selector to get all direct children?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

I wonder, if there is a difference of getting every direct child in css between

```
tag > *
```

and

```
tag > :nth-child(n)
```

I know that the universal selector is slow, but I don't know, what the nth-child selector is doing under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the universal selector is slow

No, the universal selector is *fast*, because it does *nothing* except guarantee a match (there are rare exceptions but they don't apply here). The only time it's "slow" is when you have a page with a ridiculously large number of elements (in the order of thousands) — then the browser has to run it on every element to determine if it's a child of whatever parent.

Using `:nth-child(n)` is needlessly asking the browser to evaluate an `n` expression as opposed to immediately matching the element no questions asked. Even if a browser did optimize away `:nth-child(n)`, you're left with a guaranteed match exactly the way `*` works. So you're really just wasting space by using `:nth-child(n)` (12 whole bytes longer than `*`), and not getting any computational gains out of it versus just using `*`.

Just stick with the universal selector. Or, if you're that worried about CSS selector performance, you can always add a class name to every desired child element and select that class instead, at the cost of markup bloat.

The only functional difference between `*` and `:nth-child(n)` is specificity — the specificity of `*` is zero, which is less than a pseudo-class. You generally never need the extra specificity, so again, there is no reason not to stick with `*` for this use case. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219057/programmatically-set-css-selector-specificity/44219087#44219087) for a specificity-centric use case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) the :nth-child() selector is for select an specific child, but if you want to select everything from the container, use the * selector. In the case of using :nth-child(**n**), is the same as using the * selector, and the * uses less space.

Wonder it helps.