# How to generalize a CSS rule to specific children of the same element without repeating the parent's reserved word?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

### Problem description

I would like all my `h2`, `h3`, `p` and `picture` children of an `article` to have the following css rule:

```css
margin-left: 16px;
margin-right: 16px;
```

### What am I doing

So I'm using the `>` operator in CSS:

```css
article > h2, article > h3, article > p, article > picture {
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

However this form requires a lot of repetition of the `article` keyword, and I really need these changes to only apply to children of an `article`. Is there any way to compress this rule using the word `article` only once?

### My attempt fails

I tried to do this:

```css
article > (h2, h3, p, picture) {
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

But it seems to me that it's not something acceptable for the CSS language.

Comment: `article > * ` targets all the direct children of `article`. And I recommend reading this [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) (no pun intended)

Comment: You can use the pseudo selectors `:is()`or `:where()` depending on the weight you want to give to those selectors/rules . 101 example : https://jsfiddle.net/k0ef8uwp/  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where

Comment: to complete my comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433247/what-is-the-difference-between-where-and-is/67450559 (close to be a duplicate someway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70646500/how-to-generalize-a-css-rule-to-specific-children-of-the-same-element-without-re/70647506#comment124887503_70646500), you can use one of the pseudo-classes **[`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) or [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where)** to list multiple element types at the end of your `article > …` selector:

```css
article > :is(h2, h3, p, picture) {
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<article>Inside an article:
  <h1>h1 (shouldn’t be styled)</h1>
  <h2>h2</h2>
  <p>p</p>
  <picture>Inside a pic:
    <h2>h2 that is not a direct child of the article (shouldn’t be styled)</h2>
  </picture>
</article>
```

The difference between `:is()` and `:where()` is their specificity. `:is()` takes on the specificity of the most specific selector in its arguments, while `:where()` always has 0 specificity. For more details, see [MDN: Comparing :where() and :is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where#comparing_where_and_is) or [Stack Overflow: What is the difference between :where() and :is()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67433247/578288).

Browsers started implementing support for these selectors in 2020. Browser compatibility details:
[MDN: `:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where#browser_compatibility),
[MDN: `:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#browser_compatibility),
[Can I use… `:where()`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_where),
[Can I use… `:is()`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_is).

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set up a CSS **build tool** — a CSS pre-processor or post-processor such as PostCSS, Sass, or Less — you could use nested rules in combination with the **`&` selector**:

```css
article {
    & > h2, & > h3, & > p, & > picture {
        margin-left: 16px;
        margin-right: 16px;
    }
}
```

If I pass the above to, for example, Sass as a SCSS input, it gets compiled to the CSS you want:

```css
article > h2, article > h3, article > p, article > picture {
     margin-left: 16px;
     margin-right: 16px;
}
```

#### Tool-specific notes

##### Configuration

If you are using [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss), you will need a plugin to use nesting and `&`. I am aware of two plugins that support this:

- [PostCSS Nesting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-nesting), which supports the syntax of the [draft CSS Nesting specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting-1/)
- [PostCSS Nested](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-nested), which supports syntax closer to Sass and Less

[Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) and [Less](https://lesscss.org/) require no additional configuration to use those features.

##### Documentation

Sass and Less call `&` the parent selector: [Sass docs for `&`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector), [Less docs for `&`](https://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature). The CSS Nesting specification implemented by PostCSS Nesting calls `&` the nesting selector: [CSS Nesting spec on `&`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting-1/#nest-selector).

Answer (score 0):

If you know that in your HTML, *all* children of an `article` will be elements of the types you are trying to style, you can use **`*`, the [CSS universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)**, instead of listing `h2, h3, p, picture` explicitly:

```css
article > * {
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

This will apply the given styles to all direct children of `article`. There’s no way to specify exceptions for the elements included in `*`.