# Increase specificity weight with double selector via Sass

Tags: css, sass

As mentioned here on Stack Overflow [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572081/css-class-repetition-to-increase-specificity) and MDN [tells about the specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of selectors, I want to slightly increase the weight of my selector via Sass to override some existing styles. Here's an example of the (compiled) CSS.

```css
.parent .parent__child.parent__child { color: red; }
```

It is more specific than just using `.parent .parent__child` as a selector.

---

I have a way to do this via Sass, but I think there should be a better way to do this:

```css
.parent {
    &__child.parent__child { color: red; }
}
```

Ideally, this would be the best possible setup (the ampersands have to be directly attached to each other since it's not a child selector):

```css
.parent {
    &__child&__child { color: red; }
}
```

This throws an error and adds a dot between the 'child' selectors. The [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Referencing_Parent_Selectors_____parent-selector) doesn't say anything about this particular case. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**edit**

I know about the interpolation brackets method, but what if the selector is more profound than three or four layers deep? I only want its parent selector to be duplicated, not the *whole* selector tree.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a special trick in SASS for doubling specificity using interpolation brackets (more on that [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-ever-need-to-know-about-sass-interpolation--cms-21375) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-11)) since two `&`'s next to each other is invalid SASS syntax.

```
.parent {
  &__child {
    &#{&} {
      color: red; 
    }
  } 
}

// compiles to
// .parent__child.parent__child { color: red; }

// You can also do this with deeper nested elements by
// prefacing the interpolation with the ancestor selectors:
.parent {
  &__child {
    .some .ancestor .elements &#{&} {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

// compiles to
// .some .ancestor .elements .parent__child.parent__child { color: red; }
```

For those of you who stumble upon this and use LESS, double `&&`'s are allowed:

```
.parent {
  &__child {
    && {
      color: red;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: @Roy perhaps you should break the selectors out into their own block and preface the interpolation with the parent selectors. something like `.some .ancestor .classes &#{&} { ... }` -- edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: But then again, I am writing more selectors than I want to.

Comment: @Roy there's only so much you can do to fight specificity. If you original selectors are nested 3 or 4 level deep, or more, then perhaps the original structure needs to be readdressed, or perhaps you might consider namespacing with an id. There's obvious pitfalls with this, nor would I recommend using `!important` as some do.

Comment: both `&#{&}` and `&&` are breaking the build on my typescript project